# Brazilian Keyboard layout in CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm Brazilian and new with Linux. I have the CentOS 6.5 with Gnome 2.28.2 running in a VirtualBox VM. I'm using it to PHP programming and I'm loving it. But I'm having a hard time to make accentuation.

I have a standard US International Keyboard (NOT an ABNT2 - no "cedil" key). In Windows, I choose the Brazilian Portuguese language and United States International Keyboard layout, and everything works fine. When I want to make a cedil, I just type the accent key ('), and then the C key. The same process to make accented chars, like A with tilde (~ then A).

I already tryied to search the Internet, without success... Every howto points me to ABNT2 keyboards (witch is the standard Brazilian Keyboard), but my Keyboard is the US-Intl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face-off a similar problem, I am using `CENTOS 7`, with `US Keyboard Layout`, but any dead key (a.k.a. tildes, ñ, etc) didn't work, because there was no way to install or setup a `US International Keyboard layout`.

At google, I found this suggestion:

> yum install system-config-keyboard

after that, I had available the `system-config-keyboard` and let me change the keyboard to `US International`.

[image]

btw, all these with `root`.

Regards

VieL

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these steps (from [this page](http://www.metod.si/change-keyboard-layout-in-centos-in-console/))?

```
# vi /etc/sysconfig/keyboard
and change the KEYTABLE key using these values:

KEYTABLE=”br-latin1-us”
MODEL=”latin1-us”
LAYOUT=”br”
KEYBOARDTYPE=”pc”

After that, just restart the machine.

# shutdown -r now
```

Comment: It works if my Keyboard is an ABNT2 model (with cedil key). But it's not... It's a US International Keyboard, without the cedil key.

Comment: Ok, i've checked my /lib/kbd/keymaps/i386 folder, and it have a lot of key map files. I'm starting to think my "br-lation1-us.map.gz" file is identical to "br-abnt2.map.gz" file. There's a way I can check this? There's another place I can get a verified file for this purpose?

Comment: You can view the contents of the files (and see that they are different) using `zcat br-latin1-us.map.gz` and `zcat br-latin1-abnt2.map.gz`.

Comment: Ok, the files are different and the br-latin1-us seams to be correct... But the problem persists. I'm almost giving up and buying an ABNT2 keyboard. :-(
But thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can `sudo loadkeys br-latin1-abnt2` if you use virtual console(no GUI terminal) after login; or, if you use X11, `setxkbmap br-latin1-abnt2`.(GUI)